# Android NDK - Build does not find NDK includes such as <Queue>,

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I have set up NDK as described in the installation guide, have set the PATH variable to my NDK installation.

Now when building my app in Android Studio, I'm getting a build error which says me that the include  could not be found. This is my first NDK project so I guess that something is wrong with the configuration and the compiler does not know where to look for the include files.

I have also set the NDK-directory in the local.properties - file. The compiler can be found but the includes not.

Here is the compiler output:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       D:\android-ndk-r10c\ndk-build.cmd NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\Programmieren\SoundTouch-Android-master\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-20 NDK_OUT=D:\Programmieren\SoundTouch-Android-master\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\Programmieren\SoundTouch-Android-master\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\lib APP_ABI=all
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       D:\Programmieren\SoundTouch-Android-master\app\src\main\jni\soundtouch-jni.cpp:3:17: fatal error: queue: No such file or directory
>        #include 
>                        ^
>       compilation terminated.
>       make.exe: *** [D:\Programmieren\SoundTouch-Android-master\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/soundtouch/D_\Programmieren\SoundTouch-Android-master\app\src\main\jni\soundtouch-jni.o] Error 1

I hope you have an idea and can help me.

Comment: Have you setup your OS PATHs correctly

Comment: I have one path pointing to: D:\android-ndk-r10c\ (which is the location of the NDK) in the windows environment path settings.

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause, since my NDK experience is old, but do you have a .c or .cpp file? GCC may treat a .c file as C code and thus not use the c++ includes.

Comment: Have you added some stl lib, stlport or gnustl?

Comment: Are you running the NDK inside Cygwin? (Silly question, gut have to ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your **build.gradle** includes this:

```
android.defaultConfig.ndk {
    stl "c++gnustl_static"
    abiFilter "armeabi"
}
```